# Есть ли решение транспортной задачи на php или javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

Здравствуйте, ответьте, пожалуйста, можно ли найти решение транспортной задачи на php или javascript? весь интернет перешарил, везде только C++ и Delphi. У меня курсовая работа и преподаватель требует именно языки php и javascript, но проблема у меня с ними в общем. Помогите с ответом.

Answer (score 2):

Так в чем проблема? Вы знаете C/C++, Delphi, Java? Возьмите код, который вы понимаете хотя бы более-менее и перепишите на JS или PHP, если уж сами не в состоянии написать. А по ходу дела можете задавать вопросы на этом форуме -- вам охотнее ответят.

Беглый поиск не дал результатов, я тоже не нашел решение транспортной задачи на php и javascript.